# Como llamar una funcion desde un componente a otro en vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Lo que intento hacer es que cuando en el componente 2 se ejecute la funcion   **onUpdate** se ejecute la funcion **sort** en el componente 1.

**COMPONENTE 1**

```
var container = new Vue({
        el: "#main",
        data: {
            list:[{name:"John"}, 
                    {name:"Joao"}, 
                    {name:"Jean"} ],
            },
        methods:{
    sort: function(){
    alert("Hola desde otro componente")
                }
        ,
            }
        });
```

**COMPONENTE 2**

```
  var list = document.getElementById("main");
Sortable.create(list, { 
  /* options */ 
 animation: 200, // ms, animation speed 
  ghostClass: "ghost",
  scroll: true,

    onUpdate: function (){
this.componenet1.sort();

  },

}); // That's all.
```

[CODIGO COMPLETO EN CODE OPEN](https://codepen.io/KIDRP1/pen/JeVVJj)

Comment: Cual es la relacion entre ellos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

una forma es accediendo al componente directamente

```
var list = document.getElementById("main");
Sortable.create(list, { 
/* options */ 
animation: 200, // ms, animation speed 
ghostClass: "ghost",
scroll: true,

onUpdate: function (){
componenet1.sort();
},

});
```

suerte y saludos

Answer (score 1):

Como pasar funciones como props en VueJS, desde un componente **padre** a un componente **hijo**.

- App.vue

  ```
  <template>
      <div id="app">
      <child-component :onClick="sampleFunction" :fruits="sampleData"></child-component>
      </div>
  </template>

  <script>
  import ChildComponent from './components/ChildComponent.vue'

  export default {
      name: 'app',
      data(){
      return{
          sampleData: ["Apple", "Banana", "Mango", "Strawberry"]
      }
      },
      components: {
      'child-component' : ChildComponent
      },
      methods: {
      sampleFunction(fruitName){
          alert("You have selected: " + fruitName)
      }
      }
  }
  </script>
  ```
- Componente hijo

  ```
  <template>
      <div>
          <ul>
          <li v-for="fruit in fruits">
              <button type="button" @click='onClick(fruit)'> {{ fruit }}</button>
          </li>
          </ul>
      </div>
  </template>

  <script>
  export default {
      props: {
      onClick: Function,
      fruits: Array
      }
  }
  </script>
  ```